# Can the JPA 2.0 Metamodel be used to determine both sides of a bi-directional association

Tags: rest, jpa, orm, metamodel

I am building a library that directly exposes entities within a persistence unit via a REST interface, to be included into a JAX-RS or standard web application.

In order to facilitate the usability of this library, I want the library itself to manage the setting/unsetting of bi-directional associations when necessary, in order to make the persistence and modification of complex entity relationships possible using simple state representations.

As an example, consider the typical 'Project and Employee' model, and suppose that there is a one-to-many relationship from *Project* to *Employee* - a *Project* can contain multiple *Employee* entities, and an *Employee* may only 'belong' to one *Project* at a time.

Also suppose that this relationship is bi-directional - *Employee* has a *project* property, and *Project* has a *employees* property that returns a collection of *Employee* entities who currently 'belong' to the *Project*.  The properties  *Employee.project* and *Project.employees* map the two sides of the bi-directional association.

Consider the following url:

```
PUT /Project/1/employees
```

And the accompanying (JSON) state representation

```
//Employee representation
{
   firstName: "some", 
   lastName:  "guy",
   salary: 1000000.01,
   ...
   ...
}
```

This URL/state representation combo directs my library to construct and add the *Employee* entity to the *Project.employees*  collection of the *Project* whose identification property yields the value '1'.

What I need to be able to do is, given the **standard** Metamodel API, determine if *Employee* has some property that fulfills the bi-directional side of this association, if one exists, so that I can set that property to the *Project* entity in question.

In other words, I need to be able to determine that *Employee* has a  *Employee.project* property that satisfies the bi-directional component of the *Project.employees* association.

So the state/URL combination essentially performs the following task:

```
EntityManager em = ....;

//this is the Employee represented by the state representation    
Employee employee = ..... ;

Object id = 1;
Project project = em.find( Project.class, id );
project.getPersons().add( employee );
```

I need to know **when** to do the following

```
employee.setProject( project );
```

My current implementation relies on a custom annotation that mimics the 'mapped-by' attribute in JPA 2.0 mappings, and I have planned to implement checks for the 'mapped-by' attribute value in JPA 2.0 annotations.  This works BUT, it requires proprietary configuration ( which I am trying to get rid of ), or JPA 2.0 annotations (what if someone exclusively uses mapping files?).

If anyone can point me in the right direction towards determining the properties involved in both sides of a bi-directional association when given the Entity java type and the Metamodel API, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: i'm trying to do exactly the same thing. Metamodel has too little information, and i wonder why JPA does not have an annot to manage both sides automatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that there is no way to obtain such bidirectional data from the standard Persistence Metamodel.   I've solved by my problem by using existing JPA 2.0 annotations, falling back to a custom @Bidirectional annotation if XML mapping is being used.